# Отличие тэгов в struct, enum итд

Tags: c++

Чем отличается тэг в начале struct от тэга в конце?

```
enum EnumTag{

} EnumTag2;
class ClassTag{

} ClassTag2;
```

Чем вот отличаются эти тэги?

Comment: Где ты вообще взял понятие "тег"? Никогда не встречал.

Comment: @Qwertiy например стандарт С ISO/IEC 9899 6.7.2.3 Tags

Comment: Не забыли написать `typedef` перед `enum`/`class`? Потому что сейчас `{Enum,Class}Tag2` - это просто переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В С имя структуры (struct) / перечисления (enum) / объединения (union) состоит из двух частей - ключевого слова `struct` / `enum` / `union` и опционального тэга. Чтобы не писать каждый раз ключевое слово типичным приемом в С является объявление алиаса для типа одновременно с объявлением / определением типа:

```
typedef enum EnumTag
{

} EnumTag2;

EnumTag var1; // не работает
enum EnumTag var1; // работает
EnumTag2 var2; // работает благодаря наличию typedef
```

В С++ же правила изменили и тэг стал class name и получил возможность быть использованным в большинстве контекстов сам по себе без указания ключевого слова.

---

без `typedef` в начале, как в вопросе, `EnumTag2` будет переменной.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае это часть имени перечисления (класса), во втором случае это часть имени объекта-экземпляра перечисления (класса).